# How to lock Screen Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am working on android fingerprint Screen locker. how i locked and unlocked android device Programetically. i used onTouchListner on an image and Count the time of Action_down (means thumb pressed). on Action_Down I want to code unlock.

anyone help Please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To lock your device programmatically use:

```
DevicePolicyManager deviceManger = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService( Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
```

Then call:

```
deviceManger.lockNow();
```

Wherever you need to lock it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I want to lock when app run.

Comment: Then put this 2 lines in `onCreate` method.